# Hash code for array size 600 with least collisions

Tags: java, arrays, hashcode

So I'm working with a file that has 400 data values, all ints and ranging from 4 to 20,000 in value.  I load all these into an array of size 400. There is another empty array of ListNodes of size 600 that I will move the data to, but using a self-written hash code (I'll post it below).

Because each index in the array of length 600 has a ListNode in it, if there are any collisions, then the data value is added to the back of the ListNode. I also have a method that returns the percent of the array that is null. But basically since I'm loading 400 data values into an array of size 600, the least percent of nulls I can have is 33.3% because if there are no collisions, then 400 slots in the array are taken and 200 are null, but this is not the case:

```
return (num+123456789/(num*9365))%600; //num is the value read from the array of 400
```

That hashCode has given me my best result of 48.3% nulls and I need it to be below 47% at least. any suggestions or solutions to imporve this hashCode? I would greatly appreciate any help. If you need any more info or details please let me know. Thank you!!!

Comment: You might want to look into a minimal perfect hash function (eg http://sux.di.unimi.it/docs/it/unimi/dsi/sux4j/mph/MinimalPerfectHashFunction.html). That lib seems to have a bunch of other implementations as well: http://sux.di.unimi.it/docs/it/unimi/dsi/sux4j/mph/AbstractHashFunction.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some experiments with random numbers: generate 400 uniformly distributed random numbers in the range  [0, 599] and check how many values in that range are not generated. It turns out, on average 51.3 % of the values are not generated. So your 48.3 % is already better than expected.
The target of 47 % seems unrealistic unless some form of perfect hashing is used.

If you want to make some experiments on your own, here is the program.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random r = new Random();
    int[] counts = new int[600];
    for (int i = 0; i < 400; i++) {
        counts[r.nextInt(600)]++;
    }
    int n = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 600; i++) {
        if (counts[i] == 0) {
            n++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(100.0 * n / 600);
}
```

Comment: This is related to the Law of Small Numbers. If you you generate N uniformly distributed values in the range [0;N], roughly one third of the values will not be generated, one third will be generated exactly once and one third more than once. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#Once_in_an_interval_events:_The_special_case_of_.CE.BB_.3D_1_and_k_.3D_0)

Comment: Thanks Henry, while waiting for responses, I managed to hit 47.16666%  so I will use your program to see if I can get anything lower:

Answer (score 0):

I'd use JAVAs implementation of the hashing-algorithm:

[Hava a look at open-jdk HashMap](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.hash%28int%29)

```
static int hash(int h) {
     // This function ensures that hashCodes that differ only by
     // constant multiples at each bit position have a bounded
     // number of collisions (approximately 8 at default load factor).
     h ^= (h >>> 20) ^ (h >>> 12);
     return h ^ (h >>> 7) ^ (h >>> 4);
 }
```

Note you have too add a modulo-operation to make sure that the value wouldn't be greater than 600

---

**EDIT 1**

```
>>> is logical shift right
```

EXAMPLE:

```
10000000 >>> 2 = 00100000
```

Comment: what do the arrows do? I have never seen that in java. and yes i did account for modulo by 600/599 thanks for the reminder!!